# Perl: Print everything except the pattern

Tags: regex, perl

given a file

```
input [7:0] di,     
input AEN,
```

I want to print

```
di 
AEN
```

as the output. How do I do it perl?

Could some one help me here?

Comment: Which pattern you mean?

Comment: I want to remove patters "input" and "input [num:num]"

Comment: @PrasannaVetrivel then why you remove the `,`?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not phrase my question right. I need comma removed too

Comment: so you want to remove "input" and "input [num:num]" and also the last comma. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use perl from command line,

```
perl -lane 'print $F[-1] =~ /(\w+)/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below perl one-liner command.

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?:^input\s*(?:\[\d+:\d+])?\s+|,)//g' file
di     
AEN
```